# Ajax call if textarea not in form with form nesting problem as well

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

System I working on is CMS where you insert templates like Contact form template and save that to database. This template is coded against server side to process data.

Now my "contentDiv" within form where all the templates were insert and saved than showed on the page withint form tag wrapped like

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "first" }))
{
    @Html.Hidden("someId", @Model.PageId)

}

<div id="contentDiv"  style="width:100%">@Html.Raw(Model.Html)</div>
```

Above form is than saved as

```
$(function () {
    $("form#first").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var viewmodel = {
            Id: $("#someId").val(),
            Html: $("#contentDiv").val()
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr("action"),
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(viewmodel),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            beforeSend: function () { $("#status").fadeIn(); },
            complete: function () { $("#status").fadeOut(); },
            success: function (data) {
                var message = data.Message;

            },
            error: function () {

            }
        });
    });
});
```

notice that I moved "contentDiv out of form tag as my contact form which is wrapped in a form tag can not be nested within id=first form.

**Is there a solution to form nesting?** . If not than

**My another question is**

contentDiv is not wrapped up in form tag that means if client browser has javascript disabled than he wont be able to post contentDiv data to server and form will be of no use.

What to do?

If I don't move contentDiv out of form tag than than after inserting template the structure will be nesting of forms

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "first" }))
    {
<form id="contactform" action="/Home/Email"  method="post" >                
    <div class="clear" style="padding-bottom:10px;"></div>

    <div class="formCaption">Full Name</div>
    <div class="formField"><input id="fullName" name="fullName" class="standardField" /></div>




    <div><input id="sendBtn" value="Send" type="button" /></div>
</form> 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't understand from your description why the html needs to be outside the form. Also you should not use the `.val()` method for divs. You should use `.html()`:

```
var viewmodel = {
    Id: $("#someId").val(),
    Html: $("#contentDiv").html()
};
```

Of course because you are using javascript to fetch the html which is outside of the main form if client browser has javascript disabled the form will be of no use. Only if you move the html inside the main form would this work without javascript:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "first" }))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.PageId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Html)
    <input type="submit" value="Edit" />
}

<!-- 
You could still keep the div for preview or something but don't make 
any use of it when submitting.
-->
<div id="contentDiv" style="width:100%">
    @Html.Raw(Model.Html)
</div>
```

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov , updated my question see at the bottom if i dont move contentDiv out of form.

Comment: @pirzada, I see, the HTML property on your view model might contain forms as well. Is this always the case? Do you want to actually submit those forms as well? Why do you want to submit the HTML along with the first form? Can't you fetch it from the database using the id? It would make more sense. What about the hidden field I suggested you?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov , I can not use another div for preview messup on the page as contents can be long. Someway if I could post contentDiv contents to server even if out of form tag?

Comment: @pirzada, as I said the only way to post the contents of this div to the server if it is outside of the form is to use javascript.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov  , Actually user insert full contact form in the contentDiv and than I save it to database. This is reterived when user go to contact form and submit it for emailing contact info. I use $("#contentDiv").html() to save HTML.

Comment: @pirzada, do you trust your users? Be very careful if you don't because when you use `@Html.Raw` your site becomes vulnerable to XSS attacks.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov , That is for admin use only not for public.

Comment: @pirzada, ok, then you should be safe.